# How to unlock jumbo jets?

Tags: pocket-planes

There is [a screenshot on the Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=373773512687279&set=a.373773489353948.86152.373764136021550) where you can see the player is at level 11 and has a Tetra-M. Yet I am at level 12 and the biggest planes I have are Birchcraft. Or maybe is it just because they are the developers?

Comment: It was proably a reward plane or a testing situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible for a higher-level player to gift you the parts to build a plane that you haven't yet unlocked.

However, I think this image is just a developer version of the app.

Answer (score 0):

It is because they are the developers; I haven't found a way to unlock planes ahead of my level.

Answer (score 0):

Keep checking the Market for newer planes as items are randomly added. But of course this may only pertain to your level.

Answer (score 0):

Every level yields 1 airport and 3 bux. Somewhere in the teen levels you start getting planes every other level.

After the Birchcraft is the Pearjet, then followed by the Aeroeagle. I don't know if the helicopters are a higher level unlock or unique to the "flight crew" challenges. (the casablanca challenge offered up Huey parts for example)

I'm level 18 atm, so much beyond that i'm unsure. Haven't found any parts i don't already have unlocked by buying the class 3 airports (red) or class 2 (blue) either, they just save you a few bux if your going to make a plane.

Answer (score 0):

For Christmas, Nimblebit gives you a gift everyday in December. Sometimes it's an Airvan, sometimes a Kangaroo, and sometimes ten bucks. However, on Christmas Day they give you a big gift. That is probably how he got a Tetra.